# Constructing a diffeomorphism which maps $\Gamma$ to a parabola

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, diffeomorphism

$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and 
$$\Gamma = \left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y=f(x) \right \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$$ its function graph.

a.) Construct a diffeomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$,  which maps $\Gamma$ to the parabola with the equation $y = x^2$.

b.) Show that there is no diffeomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R^2}$ which maps $\Gamma$ on the set with the equation $y = \mid x \mid$

I know from the teacher that the solution for a.) is $\varphi(x,y) \to (x, y+x^2)$.
Unfortunately, I don't see how he got to this solution. Can someone explain it to me? I can not imagine how a diffeomorphism can be mapped on a parabola.

And for b.) how do I show that there is no diffeomorphism? Do I have to show that it is not differentiable everywhere?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: "I can not imagine how a diffeomorphism can be mapped on a parabola." This was not stated anywhere. Besides, the "solution" for (a) is not correct. I would go with $\varphi(x,y) = (x,y-f(x)+x^2)$.

Comment: @amsmath how did you come up with the solution? Could you explain it to me? Thank you!

Comment: Well, when you have $(x,f(x))$ and want to end up with $(x,x^2)$, you will have to get away with the $f(x)$ somehow. So, you just subtract it from $y$ (which is exactly $f(x)$, when you are on the graph).

Comment: @amsmath Ok, thank you very much. And for b.) there is no diffeomorphism since $\mid x \mid$ is not differentiable everywhere?

Comment: Assume the contrary and use that $x\mapsto |x|$ is not differentiable at zero.